# How do I figure out where random sound is coming from?

Tags: sound

I'm using 14.04 LTS on a thinkpad. For the past week or so, I've been regularly hearing these random bubbling/popping sound (I think that'S the best way I can describe them) and I cannot for the life of me determine where it's coming from.

The only open applications are the same that I always have open, even before this started happening: Chrome, Virtual Box (with Win7), Navigator and Text Editor. And in the Icon tray, I have Skype, Dropbox, Google Chrome and Wallch (wallpaper changer).

When I open the Sound settings, under applications, all I have are two entries for Virtual Box (one with the Multimedia icon, and the other with the Microphone icon).

And I cannot see any options in VirtualBox for sound notifications or anything like that. As for my windows virtual machine, I don't have much running except Office and I don't see any popus or anything when the sound happens.

Since the sounds lasts only for a second or so, I never have enough time to switch to this window to see if another application is active. So I was wondering if there was any way to log the sound activity, so that I could go back into the file and check which process or application made the sound?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is very frustrating!
Thanks!

Comment: That bubling sound sounds like Skype, check if you have incoming calls, it could also be a video / flash running in a browser tab - commercial or news feed with the sound turned down a good way.

Comment: OK, I got it, you're right! It's Skype indeed. I don't know why but the sound notification for contacts coming online and going offline was checked, although no popups ever appeared.  Finally, mystery solved! Thanks!

Comment: @KenMollerup Why not expand your comment to an answer since you seem to have solved the problem and comments can be deleted for a number of reasons?

Comment: Thanx a lot I will try, I had the same sounds, and found Skype responsible for the main part, but still suspect adds on webpages to add to it, even if I run AddBlock edge - it works nicely - most of the time even if it blocks videos with commercials added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it is all Skype! Thanks Phybot for drawing attention to the comming online and going offline, it seems that Skype defaults to flaging our contacts as offline, when the mouse and keyboard haven't been touched for 5 minutes, see these settings:[image]
And then again when we start typing or browsing!
So now I too have altered those 2 settings:
[image]
By removing the checkmark from play sound, that was a whole lot of unwanted sound/noise to get rid of!