# Hearing music without anything being open

Tags: sound

I have no programs running at the moment except Chrome but I still hear music and I don't know how to stop it.

[image]

Comment: Try restarting your computer.
Also try doing a hard shutdown. Do you use skype, if so go here: https://askubuntu.com/a/607297/678821

Comment: What happens if you close Chrome?