# How to shut off random notification sounds after Ubuntu 20.04 upgrade?

Tags: sound

I recently upgraded to 20.04, and now have random, frequent, and annoying sounds happening that sound like notifications. I have no idea what's causing them or how to disable them.  I tried turning on do not disturb in notifications settings, and adjusting the bar in sound settings system sounds, but I don't want to turn all sound off, just to stop the random notifications that are so distracting. I have now put Skype and Zoom on Do Not Disturb and logged out of them to check, but still have the issue.  Also, it happens whether I am online or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I figure out where random sound is coming from?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607219/how-do-i-figure-out-where-random-sound-is-coming-from)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!  I just put Skype on Do Not Disturb, but it's still making the sound.

Comment: I have just figured out another potential source of these sounds: a telephone connected to the computer. My phone just restarted and when my computer tried to mount its file access while the phone was still locked that failed and caused Ubuntu to make the "bong" sound it makes when an error occurs. Normally it shows a popup saying "Couldn't mount mtp://whatevertheaddressis!" but this time it didn't.